# gRPC is failing because of TLS Certificate

Tags: ssl, microservices, grpc, tls1.2

I have created a gRPC client and server applications .I am using default TLS mde of communication but my gRPC call is failing.

Below are the certificate which i created on own

```
//Generate CA's private key 
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca.key.pem

//create CA's self-signed certificate
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key.pem -sha256 -days 365 -out ca.cert.pem

//create private key for server
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048

//create certificate signing request (CSR)
openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr

//Use CA's private key to sign web server's CSR and get back the signed certificate
openssl x509 -req -in ca.csr -CA ca.cert.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -out ca.crt -days 365

//convert server private key in PKCS8 standard(gRPc expects)
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in ca.key -out ca.pem
```

server application-->application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9001

grpc:
  server:
    security:
      enabled: true
       certificate-chain: file:certs/ca.crt
       private-key: file:certs/ca.pem
    port: 9000
```

Client Application-->application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8000

grpc:
  client:
    banks-data:
      address: static://localhost:9000
      negotiation-type: TLS
      security:
        trust-cert-collection: file:certs/ca.cert.pem
```

Below is the error i get when it client api

```
2023-05-26 13:55:45.482 ERROR 18172 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]] with root cause

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:452) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:292) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:234) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:717) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:634) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1258) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1384) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1427) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:208) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1358) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1253) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1300) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1347) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1308) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Any inputs shall be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: *"No name matching localhost found"*  means that your certificate is not issued for "localhost".  While you provide the commands you've used to create the certificate it is unclear what values and configuration you've used for these commands - but likely the wrong ones.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich can u please share any link which will help me in creating TLS certificate so that i can use it in my gRPC call?

Comment: By [using a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+self-signed+certificate+for+gprc+localhost) I get [How to setup and test TLS in gRPC/gRPC-Web](https://itnext.io/how-to-setup-and-test-tls-in-grpc-grpc-web-1b67cc4413e6) which looks good from a cursory look.